# How to replace a string within a block

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, if-statement, block

I have a problem with an if condition that I want to use within a block. More precisely I want to get a string from an array, change that string and save it back to the array if a certain condition holds.

I have an array called "leuchtturmgesamtheit" which consists of strings.
Most of those strings look like this:

ACH-92941100

ACH-92941102

My aim is to aggregate those two strings. Thats why I want to rename the strings so that they have the same name. To do that I want to cut of the last character. After that I can use uniq! on the array.

Here is what I did:

```
leuchtturmgesamtheit.each { |replace|

  if replace.count("1234567890")==8
    replace=replace[0...-1]
  end

}

leuchtturmgesamtheit.uniq!

print leuchtturmgesamtheit
```

I expected to get:

> ACH-9294110

But instead I get the same two strings back.

RubyMine tells me that the bold marked "replace" is a local variable not used after assignment. So the problem seems to be the if condition inside the block. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace=replace[0...-1]` is only changing which string the local variable within the block refers to and is not updating the entries in the array. There are a couple of solutions.

One is to use `each_with_index` and update the actual strings in the array:

e.g.

```
leuchtturmgesamtheit.each_with_index do |replace, index|
  if replace.count("1234567890") == 8
    leuchtturmgesamtheit[index] = replace[0...-1]
  end
end
```

another is to use `map!` to update the array e.g.

```
leuchtturmgesamtheit.map! do |entry|
  if entry.count("1234567890") == 8
    entry[0...-1]
  else
    entry
  end
end
```

---

[steenslag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741383/63034) is also good for scenarios where the string manipulation needed can be done on methods that modify the existing string, as is the case here.

Comment: Thx a lot for that quick and precise answer =)

Comment: Or you could use `map!` in the same way to replace in-place and save a few characters (the `leuchtturmgesamtheit = `)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each` if you use a method which alters the strings in-place (in stead of producing an altered copy):

```
words = %w[ACH-92941100 ACH-92941102]
words.each{|word| word.chop! if word.count('1234567890') == 8 }
p words  #=> ["ACH-9294110", "ACH-9294110"]
```